# I am overstepping the *image array by 2 bytes and am not sure why that is

Tags: c, cs50

I am getting the following scary memory error with this message:

> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
> ==6297==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7f37601962a8 (pc 0x000000425b02 bp 0x7ffe24ab7140 sp 0x7ffe24ab6fe0
> T6297)
> ==6297==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
> #0 0x425b01  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x425b01)
> #1 0x42332b  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x42332b)
> #2 0x7f375efc9b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
> #3 0x402e19  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x402e19)
>
> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
> ==6297==ABORTING

I'm not sure where it is since I'm new to pointers. Basically in this lil' homework assignment, I am flipping an image (doing so by swapping pixels on the left and right sides of the image).

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE tmp;
    int middlePixel;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        if (width % 2 != 0) { // put this here since it would change with each row, not each pixel
        
            middlePixel = ceil(width / 2); // hopefully ceil will round up the number from .5
        }
        
        for (int j  = 0; j < ceil(width / 2) - 1; j++) { //what does ceil do if it's already an integer?
        
            RGBTRIPLE a = image[i][j];
            RGBTRIPLE b = image[i][width - j];
            tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
                
            if (j == middlePixel) {
                
                break; // I want it to go to next loop of i. End middle loop at width /2  -1 
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    return;
    
}
```

I really don't understand how this is overstepping the array. Running help50 valgrind, here is the helper message I'm given:

> Looks like you're trying to access 2 bytes of memory that isn't yours?
> Did you try to index into an array beyond its bounds? Take a closer
> look at line 85 of helpers.c.

Comment: `width - j` is out of range when `j` is 0.

Comment: I didn't see `height` being used at all in the `for` loops, is this intentional? Also, since you know the `heightxwidth` of `image`, you can change `RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]` in function argument to just `RGBTRIPLE **image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RGBTRIPLE b = image[i][width - j];
```

You want `image[i][width - 1 - j];` since the index of the last accessible cell in the row is `width - 1`.

Also, for your rounding, use `middlePixel = (width + 1) / 2;` Your division results in an int that had already lost the fraction and thus ciel has nothing to work with (and going back and forth between int and float is something to be avoided when possible) as integer division always truncates (-3 / 2 -> -1), but you're working with positive ints anyway.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for the tips,  I actually tried doing that, but it was in the wrong order (I did width - j - 1. Derp). One last thing, now help50 valgrind is telling me that 1 byte is out of range in RGBTRIPLE a = image[i][j];. Do you know why that is? ><

Comment: Your outer loop should have `< height` rather than `< width`.
Also...
 `middlePixel` is not needed, swapping a pixel with itself is slower, but no harm.
You're not actually swapping your values as `a` and `b` are local variables (you need to write them back to the array).